# Installing Liferay IDE in Eclipse with Oracle Enterprise Pack

Tags: eclipse, oracle, liferay, liferay-ide

Has anyone been able to successfully install the Oracle Enterprise Pack for Eclipse AND the Liferay IDE?  There seems to be a mutually exclusive dependency on the Sapphire stuff and I can't find a hack for installing both.

Here is the error given by Eclipse when trying to install the Liferay IDE:

```
Cannot complete the install because of a conflicting dependency.
  Software being installed: Liferay IDE 1.3.1.v201108310601 (com.liferay.ide.eclipse.tools.feature.group 1.3.1.v201108310601)
  Software currently installed: Oracle Web Tier Tools 1.7.3.201107052114 (oracle.eclipse.tools.indigo.webtier.feature.group 1.7.3.201107052114)
  Only one of the following can be installed at once: 
    Sapphire Modeling Framework 0.2.3.201106221307 (org.eclipse.sapphire.modeling 0.2.3.201106221307)
    Sapphire Modeling Framework 0.3.0.201106221325 (org.eclipse.sapphire.modeling 0.3.0.201106221325)
  Cannot satisfy dependency:
    From: Liferay Portlet Core 1.5.0.v201108310601 (com.liferay.ide.eclipse.portlet.core 1.5.0.v201108310601)
    To: bundle org.eclipse.sapphire.modeling 0.3.1
  Cannot satisfy dependency:
    From: Liferay IDE 1.3.1.v201108310601 (com.liferay.ide.eclipse.tools.feature.group 1.3.1.v201108310601)
    To: com.liferay.ide.eclipse.portlet.core [1.5.0.v201108310601]
  Cannot satisfy dependency:
    From: Oracle Web Tier Tools 1.7.3.201107052114 (oracle.eclipse.tools.indigo.webtier.feature.group 1.7.3.201107052114)
    To: oracle.eclipse.tools.webtier.jsf [4.0.2.201107052114]
  Cannot satisfy dependency:
    From: Oracle WebLogic Server Tools 4.0.2.201107052114 (oracle.eclipse.tools.weblogic 4.0.2.201107052114)
    To: bundle org.eclipse.sapphire.modeling [0.2.3,0.3.0)
  Cannot satisfy dependency:
    From: Oracle Web Tier Tools JSF 4.0.2.201107052114 (oracle.eclipse.tools.webtier.jsf 4.0.2.201107052114)
    To: bundle oracle.eclipse.tools.weblogic [4.0.2,4.1.0)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Latest release of Liferay IDE requires a specific version of Sapphire to operate so it cannot be co-installed with Oracle that also requires a specific version that is different.

The only workaround would be to download the Liferay IDE source and build it manually and before building it, open up the valid version range for the sapphire requirements on all download Liferay IDE plugins (5 of them have sapphire deps).  Note: this would mean that any time a sapphire based feature in Liferay IDE actually hit something that was required it may fail but everything else would work normally. If you are interested in going this far to fix this problem I will be glad to help but we should continue that conversation here: [Liferay IDE Forums](http://www.liferay.com/community/forums/-/message_boards/category/4627757)

Answer (score 0):

I got the solution. Install oracle pack first and then install liferay Ide plugin.It worked for me